# Who is the murderer in the beginning of Tucker & Dale vs Evil?

Tags: plot-explanation, tucker-and-dale-vs-evil

In the first minute of [Tucker and Dale vs Evil (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1465522/), there's a scene involving a young woman and a camera man investigating a murder scene. Both are killed, and we briefly see their murderer. Who is it?

My guess is Chad, due to the similarity of the burns, but that's hard to believe considering how his face pierced a pole three days earlier, or is it just a random person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is [Chad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_&_Dale_vs_Evil). It becomes quite evident towards the ending of the movie where he is revealed to be the son of the actual memorial day killer.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the full movie, you will see that it was Chad. Do you  remember the camera man and the girl at the end, that was them, which means Chad survived as the next memorial day killer.